# Can't connect to ganache

Tags: python, localhost, solidity, ganache

the code is in the picture below

[image: 1]

ERROR:

```
raise MissingSchema(error)
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '<web3.main.Web3 object at 0x00000292C9A8C6A0>': No scheme supplied. Perhaps you meant http://<web3.main.Web3 object at 0x00000292C9A8C6A0>?
```

Answer (score 0):

Ｍissing schema means you haven't supplied the http:// or https:// in your w3 URL variable.

1. try to print w3 to see if it complies with the schema needs.
2. try to update w3

original:

```
w3 = Web3(HTTPProvider('HTTP://0.0.0.0:7545'))
```

update:

```
w3 = Web3(HTTPProvider('http://0.0.0.0:7545'))
```

Comment: yeah, it compiled when i printed w3

Comment: but @ /SimpleStorage = w3.eth.contract(abi=abi, bytecode=bytecode/   it displayed error

Comment: @JohnsonJardocs "contract" error becomes another question. do you want to close this question and open a new one or can you just post your entire codes and error messages in the text - I am hard to give you an advice by just looking at your picture?

Comment: this aside, i have another error, at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ganache-cli\build\ganache-core.node.cli.js:55:64488)\n at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)\n at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)', 'name': 'Error'}}*

Comment: i was trying to deploy a smart contract via ganache-cli and i got that error timeout, please do you know how i can fix it

Comment: understand @JohnsonJardocs but if you don't post your codes in the text format, people are hard to help you.